# Keep triangles edges visible and the rest hidden

Tags: css, animation, transform

im working on a animation that when we are hovering over a triangle, the triangle moves and shows content that was previously hidden.

[What i´ve done](http://optential.co.nf/)

It works fine, but isnt responsive, on my pc its fine but when i resize my window the triangles appear on middle of the screen or random places, how can i mantain the position, in order to only the black triangle is visible ?

My code, just in case:

```css
body{
    height:100%;
    background-color: grey;
}

/* AVISO :: Começo da animação trianglo lado esquerdo :: AVISO  */

#container {
 top:35%;
 margin-left: -19.5%;
 background-color: transperent;
 width:355px;
}

.pencil-body {
   background-color: red;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 75px;
   width: 100px;
}

.pencil-tip {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 75px solid transparent;
   border-left: 100px solid black;
   border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
   display: inline-block;
}

#container:hover {
    transform: translate(200px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(200px,0); /** Chrome & Safari **/
}

/* AVISO :: Fim da animação trianglo lado esquerdo :: AVISO  */

/* AVISO :: Começo da animação trianglo lado direito :: AVISO  */

#container2 {
 float:right;
 margin-left:92.5%;
 top:35%;
 width:355px;
}

.pencil-body2 {
 float:right;
   background-color: red;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 75px;
   width: 100px;
}

.pencil-tip2{
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 75px solid transparent;
   border-right: 100px solid black;
   border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
}

#container2:hover {
    transform: translate(-200px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,200); /** Chrome & Safari **/
}

/* AVISO :: Fim da animação trianglo lado direito :: AVISO  */

.animation {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Chrome & Safari **/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Teste1 </title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden;">

<div id="container" class="animation"> 

<div class="pencil-body"></div>
<div class="pencil-tip"></div>

</div>

<div id="container2" class="animation"> 

<div class="pencil-body2"></div>
<div class="pencil-tip2"></div>

</div>

</body>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
left: -255px;
```

and

```
right: -255px;
```

instead of using margins.

For example:

```
#container {
    left: -255px;
}

#container2 {
    right: -255px;
}
```

Also you should use html5 if you can.
This is the basic setup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8>
       <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

example:
http://jsbin.com/lihuzoxube/edit?html,css,output